# Verifying that an existing contact in Salescloud can subscribe again (update) via a subscription cloud page - AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to check if a contact already exists in Sales Cloud, when subscribing via a Cloud Page. If so, the contact needs to be updated. If not, I want a new lead to be created. I keep getting a HTTP 500 error.

**This is my code:**

```
     if @mode == "signup" then
   set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('account', 'Id,Email', 'Email', '=', @email) 
   set @optin_confirmed = false
   set @optout = false
     if RowCount(@rows) == 1 then
     set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('account',@sfID,'LastName', @email, 'Email_Opt_In__c', @optin_true, 'Email_Opt_In_confirmed__c', @optin_confirmed,  'PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail', @optout,  'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
     else 
     set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('lead',@sfID, 'LastName', @email,'Email_Opt_In__c', @optin_true, 'Email_Opt_In_confirmed__c', @optin_confirmed, 'HasOptedOutOfEmail', @optout, 'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
else 
set @result = CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 6, 'Email', @email, 'LastName', @email, 'Email_Opt_In__c', @optin_true, 'OptIn_Registration_Date__c', @today, 'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
 endif
endif
```

The URL I am using is: `https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/(cloudpage here)?mode=signup&email=test.test@gmx.de&sfid=(matching, existing sfid here)`

Comment: Hi Saskia..did my explanation work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The middle if statement is not closed properly. Try this.

```
if @mode == "signup" then
    set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('account', 'Id,Email', 'Email', '=', @email) 
    set @optin_confirmed = false
    set @optout = false
    if RowCount(@rows) == 1 then
        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('account',@sfID,'LastName', @email, 'Email_Opt_In__c', @optin_true, 'Email_Opt_In_confirmed__c', @optin_confirmed,  'PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail', @optout,  'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
    else 
        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('lead',@sfID, 'LastName', @email,'Email_Opt_In__c', @optin_true, 'Email_Opt_In_confirmed__c', @optin_confirmed, 'HasOptedOutOfEmail', @optout, 'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
    endif
else 
    set @result = CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 6, 'Email', @email, 'LastName', @email, 'Email_Opt_In__c', @optin_true, 'OptIn_Registration_Date__c', @today, 'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
endif
```

Also

```
set @result = CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 6, 'Email', @email, 'LastName', @email, 'Email_Opt_In__c', @optin_true, 'OptIn_Registration_Date__c', @today, 'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
 endif
```

Also the 'LastName' does not have a corresponding value , so this is also incomplete (i.e @lastname)

Comment: Or are you trying to set the lastname to be the email address?