# Update Account or Lead on Salescloud via CloudPage on Marketing Cloud not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, cloudpage

I want to check if an account or lead already exists in Sales Cloud when subscribing to a newsletter via a cloud page. If so, the account or lead needs to be updated. If not, a new lead needs to be created, I'm using the following code.

```
if @mode == "signup" then

    set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('account', 'Id,PersonEmail', 'PersonEmail', '=', @Email)
    set @rows1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('lead', 'Id,Email', 'Email', '=', @Email)
    set @optin_confirmed = false
    set @optout = false

    if RowCount(@rows) == 1 then
        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('account',@sfid,'LastName','test')
    elseif RowCount(@rows1) == 1 then
        set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('lead',@sfid, 'LastName', 'test')         
    else
        set @result = CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 6, 'Email', @email, 'LastName', @email,'Email_Opt_In__c',@optin_true,'OptIn_Registration_Date__c',@today,'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
    endif

endif
```

- If I enter a new email, the lead is created.
- When I enter an existing email, nothing happen (should update
  LastName)

Comment: This is a duplicate for which I provided a possible solution https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176538/verifying-that-an-existing-contact-in-salescloud-can-subscribe-again-update-vi

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Judging by your code you will get a 500 error as the first "IF" is not closed

Comment: Code edited. there is no error but the update is not working

Comment: Have you tried a test scenario where it create a lead? Is this working?

Comment: How are you passing the SFID to it?

Comment: Yes, the last statement (CreateSalesforceObject) is working but not the two Update even if I enter an existing email address

Comment: I modified the code by passing email instead of ID but it's not working. (code edited)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the below code will solve it for you. LastName, FirstName, Email and a few other are essentially contact fields. Try this below:

```
%%[
if @mode == "signup" then

  set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Id','Email', 'Id', '=', @sfid)
  set @rows1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('lead', 'Id','Email', 'Id', '=', @sfid)
  set @optin_confirmed = false
  set @optout = false

  if (RowCount(@rows) == 1 AND RowCount(@rows1) == 0) then
    set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('contact',@sfid,'LastName','test')
  elseif (RowCount(@rows1) == 1 AND RowCount(@rows) == 0) then
    set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('lead',@sfid, 'LastName', 'test')         
  else
    set @result = CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 6, 'Email', @email, 'LastName', @email,'Email_Opt_In__c',@optin_true,'OptIn_Registration_Date__c',@today,'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
  endif
endif
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ; I would advise hardcoding the SFID to test it

```
   if @mode == "signup" then

  set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('account', 'Id','PersonEmail', 'Id', '=', @sfid)
  set @rows1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('lead', 'Id','Email', 'Id', '=', @sfid)
  set @optin_confirmed = false
  set @optout = false

  if (RowCount(@rows) == 1 AND RowCount(@rows1) == 0) then
    set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('account',@sfid,'LastName','test')
  elseif (RowCount(@rows1) == 1 AND RowCount(@rows) == 0) then
    set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('lead',@sfid, 'LastName', 'test')         
  else
    set @result = CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 6, 'Email', @email, 'LastName', @email,'Email_Opt_In__c',@optin_true,'OptIn_Registration_Date__c',@today,'Email_Newsletter_Language__c', @language, 'CountryCode', @country )
  endif
endif
```

Comment: The same .... nothing happen.

Comment: if you look at the code, there is a comma issue with 'Id,PersonEmail' and Id,Email'. I am updating my answer . This should work

Comment: or is "Id.PersonEmail" an SF field?

Comment: No, the syntax for retreivesalesforceobjects : Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Lead", "Id, FirstName,LastName", "region", "=", "west"). You can check the documentation.

Comment: Ah got it. Well hopefully someone else on here can solve this